# How to add script for date field, with noConflict

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to add a **script for my GravityForm** that uses the **datepicker +3 option**. It seemsthat whenever i put it in my hooks areas of my themes, it **conflicts** with other jQuery scripts like Revolution Slider, totally putting it out of commission.

So, I'm hoping for some help in where/how else I might be able to place the script so that it functions without conflict.

I've tried adding it to the child theme's header in various locations with no luck.

• I had placed the script in the page itself and it actually worked for a little while, when WP 4.2.3 kicked in the script stopped working.

Ultimately i just need to limit the date field in my 1 form to 3 days out..

The script i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $( "#input_1_14" ).datepicker({ minDate: '+3d', gotoCurrent: true, prevText: '', showOn: 'both', buttonImage: '/wp-    content/plugins/gravityforms/images/calendar.png', buttonImageOnly: true });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Gravityforms uses the jQueryUI Datepicker so you can use the minDate and maxDate options for date range.

You can also use [this plugin](https://gravityplus.pro/gravity-forms-limit-date-range/)